# Connect to serial port of VirtualBox guest via host socket

Tags: virtualbox, serial-port, socket

I created a serial port in VirtualBox that maps to the host socket device: `/tmp/xxx`. But I haven't managed to find the way to use this file for anything. I can't ssh to it, so what tool can I use to interact with it?

`ls -la` shows it is a socket link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the serial port mapped to the socket file on the host provides a serial console, you can connect to it using a control and terminal emulation program such as [`minicom`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/minicom) or [GTKTerm](http://gtkterm.feige.net/).

In `minicom` you can specify the socket file as the device to connect using the `--device|-D` command line option, or in the `minicom` configuration file, for example:

`$ minicom -D unix\#/tmp/xxx`

In GTKTerm the same can be achieved by modifying the *Port* under *Configuration* > *Port* menu.

Comment: It says - operation not supported on socket

Comment: Ok - it worked with minicom -D unix\#/tmp/xxx